# Considering VAT being used by the government to pay interest-based loans, is buying things in shops haram?

Tags: halal-haram, riba

Each country (except a few, probably) takes loans from central banks, and then uses this money for various purposes. To pay back that money, they  take taxes and VAT that people pay, and pay their interest based loan. So every time I buy a Samsung phone on the Samsung website, Samsung the company will pay some VAT to the government (this is also true for KFC, shopping centers, etc.), who in turn will use it to pay their interest based loan

Can I safely buy some chocolate, or unnecessary groceries at shops?

Answer (score 1):

Allah doesn't not hold you accountable for what you don't have control over. You are free to buy halal products from any store.

> لَا يُكَلِّفُ ٱللَّهُ نَفْسًا إِلَّا وُسْعَهَا
>
> Allah burdens not a person beyond his scope. Quran 2:286

Comment: does that mean i can promote sins , and say it's up to them to sin or not , i'm not controlling them to do the sin

Comment: The verse you quoed doesn't say Allah will not punish me over what i don't have control over , it talks about the obligations Allah put on a person ;  Besides , Allah says ;" do not help each other in sin and transgression"

Answer (score 0):

As to common fiqh, each individual is responsible for his and her deeds and omissions. The commandments are in first place directed to each individual. Our responsibility for the sins of others is limited. We are allowed to have commercial relations with disbelievers or sinners as long as we do not encourage them in it or profit indirectly (e.g. buy stolen goods or work in a riba bank.) Only an appointed judge is obliged to punish transgressions of others.

Nevertheless, the commandments concern the society as a whole, and it is legitimate to apply the verse (2:276)

> God condemns usury, and He blesses charities

also to states, communities and societies.
The present system is clearly against this commandment. A system based on interest free help and charity should be established.

It's a good task to a believer who is capable of it to find ways to change the system in the sense of the Quran and it is a task of the community to try to make it true. This it cannot be solved on an individual level and no fiqh supposes that God will hold you (and me) liable for living in this system.